# How to use Spark Job to overwrite data for multiple directories respectively?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, etl, amazon-emr

I have an S3 bucket `my-bucket` which contains a parent directory: `s3://my-bucket/data/favorites/`. Inside this directory, there are a few child directories based on some properties as below:

i. `s3://my-bucket/data/favorites/property1a/property2a`

ii.`s3://my-bucket/data/favorites/property1a/property2b`

iii. `s3://my-bucket/data/favorites/property1b/property2a`

iv. `s3://my-bucket/data/favorites/property1b/property2b`

v. `s3://my-bucket/data/favorites/property1c/property2a`

vi.`s3://my-bucket/data/favorites/property1c/property2b`

Inside each of the above directories, as shown below, I have multiple Parquet files partitioned by some variables/columns in my data:

i. `.../col1=1a/col2=2a/file1.snappy.parquet`

ii. `.../col1=1a/col2=2b/file5.snappy.parquet`

iii. `.../col1=1b/col2=2a/file16.snappy.parquet`

iv. `.../col1=1b/col2=2b/file29.snappy.parquet`

Any parquet file has just 2 columns: `user-id` and `favourite-number`, with several rows. Given a list `arr` of `user-id`(s) as Input, I want to find each of those `user-id` across all my Parquet files (throughout entire S3 structure) and delete them wherever found. For each `user-id` received in `arr`, I also want to return a response indicating whether the `user-id` was FoundAndDeleted or it was NotFound. I am thinking of using Spark-Scala (e.g. through AWS Glue or EMR) for this (mostly, Spark dataframes).

Please let me know your thoughts on how I can go about doing the find & deletion process in a way that my S3 directory structure does not get affected. It's fine if the Parquet files (or file-names) get changed but the directory structure should remain intact.

Comment: Perhaps you should talk to the other people in your class who posted this exact question. Maybe combine the questions into a single one so that you don't waste the time of people on this site.